# Problem translation in access custom r/w location at runtime in ngx-translate http loader

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript, ngx-translate

I need to load json files of after login then with token download file at location and pickup using custom http loader (TranslateHttpLoader). It can access assets/i18n/ but that not writable file/folder location fileSystemModule.knownFolders.currentApp(). so instead on that fileSystemModule.knownFolders.documents() is read and write but not accessible by TranslateHttpLoader

Made folder and write the file in knownFolders.documents() language json. and tried access using http 
let lpath = knownFolders.documents().getFolder('i18n');
return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, lpath.path, '.json');

```js
.
.
.
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {  HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

let lpath = knownFolders.documents().getFolder('i18n');

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, lpath.path +'/', '.json');
  }

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptHttpClientModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
    ],
.
.
.
```

Translation should work. 
But shows error not find the path

Also tried using the custom handler

```js
  @Injectable()
  export class CustomLoader implements TranslateLoader {

                                            // in our case that is locales/en.locales.properties
    private readonly documents = knownFolders.documents();
    private readonly folder = this.documents.getFolder('i18n');

    // public getFile({ url, code }:  ): Observable<Object> {
    //     let file = this.folder.getFile();

    //     return from(file.readText())
    //             .pipe(map((response) => {
    //                 return { response, fileType }
    //             }));
    // }


    getTranslation(lang: string) {

        return from( this.folder.getFile(lang + '.json').readText())



  }
}

 TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useClass: CustomeLoader,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you need to load the json file via a file access call and not via a http call?

Comment: Don't want to make http request to server instead to local file only

Comment: When calling getTranslation in your CustomLoader, what exactly is the content of this.folder before calling getFile(..) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your `i18n` files are not getting bundled by webpack.
If this is the case you need to add `CopyWebpackPlugin` to `webpack.config.js`, for example you could add a line to the existing `CopyWebpackPlugin` configuration:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
    { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
    { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
    { from: { glob: "i18n/*.json" } },
]
```

On a second note, you could use an `http` call to get your local json file (however this is a personal choice), like this:

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getLangFile(lang: string) {
    const content: Observable<any> = this.http.get(`/18n/${lang}.json`);
    // do something
  }
```